# How can I filter this array on the bases of value of subarray that the user will tell key and its value

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

If user give the input `var key="value_0"` and `var input="hello"` then how can I filter this array on the bases of the user given values that will be in a subarray in typescript like according to the upper given input it will filter only those in which `list.data` have `key="value_0"` and value of the this key if include this  `input="hello"` it will check by `.includes` method

```js
public list: any = [{
    "header": "API",
    "data": [{
        "value_0": "hello",
        "value_1": "abc",
        "value_2": "def",
        "value_3": "ghn",
        "value_4": "l"
      },
      {
        "value_0": "hello",
        "value_1": "abc",
        "value_2": "def",
        "value_3": "ghi",
        "value_4": "jkl"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "header": "CLOUD",
    "data": [{
        "value_0": "hello",
        "value_1": "abc",
        "value_2": "def",
        "value_3": "ghi",
        "value_4": "jkl"
      },
      {
        "value_0": "hello",
        "value_1": "abc",
        "value_2": "def",
        "value_3": "ghi",
        "value_4": "jkl"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "header": "OTHER HEADER",
    "data": [{
        "value_0": "hello",
        "value_1": "abc",
        "value_2": "def",
        "value_3": "ghi",
        "value_4": "jkl"
      },
      {
        "value_0": "yello",
        "value_1": "abc",
        "value_2": "def",
        "value_3": "ghi",
        "value_4": "jkl"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "header": "YET ANOTHER HEADER",
    "data": [{
        "value_0": "hello",
        "value_1": "abc",
        "value_2": "def",
        "value_3": "ghi",
        "value_4": "jkl"
      },
      {
        "value_0": "hello",
        "value_1": "abc",
        "value_2": "def",
        "value_3": "ghi",
        "value_4": "jkl"
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

If the user give the `key => value_o` and `input=> hel`
then we have to filter the above list like we have to go inside the data and search for this `key =>` if we found then check that its value include that text which the user is given input `=>hell`
and the result will be the filtered array which have the key and value include user input So, for `key=>'value_0'` and `input ='hell'` result will be the same because in each index the data attribute have subarray and in sub array the attribute `value_0` exists and its value have the text which user give in input.

```js
[
  {
    "header": "API",
    "data": [{
        "value_0": "hello",
        "value_1": "abc",
        "value_2": "def",
        "value_3": "ghn",
        "value_4": "l"
      },
      {
        "value_0": "hello",
        "value_1": "abc",
        "value_2": "def",
        "value_3": "ghi",
        "value_4": "jkl"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "header": "CLOUD",
    "data": [{
        "value_0": "hello",
        "value_1": "abc",
        "value_2": "def",
        "value_3": "ghi",
        "value_4": "jkl"
      },
      {
        "value_0": "hello",
        "value_1": "abc",
        "value_2": "def",
        "value_3": "ghi",
        "value_4": "jkl"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "header": "OTHER HEADER",
    "data": [{
        "value_0": "hello",
        "value_1": "abc",
        "value_2": "def",
        "value_3": "ghi",
        "value_4": "jkl"
      },
      {
        "value_0": "yello",
        "value_1": "abc",
        "value_2": "def",
        "value_3": "ghi",
        "value_4": "jkl"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "header": "YET ANOTHER HEADER",
    "data": [{
        "value_0": "hello",
        "value_1": "abc",
        "value_2": "def",
        "value_3": "ghi",
        "value_4": "jkl"
      },
      {
        "value_0": "hello",
        "value_1": "abc",
        "value_2": "def",
        "value_3": "ghi",
        "value_4": "jkl"
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Comment: anyone able to understand the requirement?

Comment: I'm guess my guessing is near author's problem meaning... But I'm not sure that my guessing guessing is right.

Comment: please add some use cases with result as well.

Comment: @NinaScholz now read the text i entered below the lcode

Comment: you can do a loop to iterate the array

Comment: please add the wanted result as well.

Comment: @AgamBanga how can i loop its the real question its what i demanding

Comment: @HASSANMEHMOOD i have added an answer. let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)

```
any.map(el=>({header:el.header,data: el.data.filter(data=>data[key] && data[key].includes(input))})).filter(el=>el.data.length);
```

Outputs:

```
...
data: [ 
 {
 value_0: "hello",
 value_1: "abc",
 value_2: "def",
 value_3: "ghi",
 value_4: "jkl"
 }
 //second obj removed, as it contains yello != hel 
 ],
 header: "OTHER HEADER"
  ...
```

http://jsbin.com/higopoloka/edit?console,js

2)If you just want the 'value_0' appear instead of the whole enclosing array, you can do:

```
any.map(el=>({header:el.header,data: el.data.reduce((arr,obj)=>obj[key]&&obj[key].includes(input)?!arr.push([obj[key]])||arr:arr,[])})).filter(el=>el.data.length);
```

Output:

```
[{
   data: [],//ive removed the value_0 here to show what happens
   header: "API"
  },
  {
    data: [["hello"], ["hello"]],
    header: "CLOUD"
  },
  {
   data: [["hello"]],//only one, as yello !== hel
   header: "OTHER HEADER"
  },
  {
   data: [["hello"], ["hello"]],
   header: "YET ANOTHER HEADER"
 }]
```

1/2) If you also want the main elems to hide if their data is empty, do this ( which is already part of the upper codes):

```
.filter(el=>el.data.length);
```

http://jsbin.com/qabenedite/edit?js,console

Comment: please list down the exact answer by combine these both

Comment: i only need first one

Comment: i mean to say your first answer result is all what i need

Comment: @HASSAN MEHMOOD perfect ;) glad to help

Comment: hey one this is missing that i want and you do that wrong that is you are checking the .includes in the key but i have to check the .includes in that key's value

Comment: @HASSANMEHMOOD nope it does... data[key].includes(input) ... data[key] is the keys value...

Comment: its working on that key but its not performing includes(input)

Comment: its mapping all elements not those which have input value

Comment: @HASSANMEHMOOD if you want api to hide in the upper example add the code 1/2 at the end...

Comment: your first code is not working well its not mapping those which have include the input but its maps all, even which not includes input.

Comment: yes i need to remove the main elems also if their data is empty in first code and what will be finall code of first after add this also

Comment: @HASSANMEHMOOD ive copied it to the row so that youre able to get it...

Comment: jonas w its not working fine it also map those values whose value not includes the input value

Comment: its not working fine it also map those values whose value not includes the input value

Comment: its working good thankyou so much for help i am thankful to you really thanks

Comment: but i cant get the concept

Answer (score 0):

You can use the loop in javascript to iterate the array & check if found in that. Please see the snippet

```js
var list = [{"header":"API","data":[{"value_0":"hello","value_1":"abc","value_2":"def","value_3":"ghn","value_4":"l"},{"value_0":"hello","value_1":"abc","value_2":"def","value_3":"ghi","value_4":"jkl"}]},{"header":"CLOUD","data":[{"value_0":"hello","value_1":"abc","value_2":"def","value_3":"ghi","value_4":"jkl"},{"value_0":"hello","value_1":"abc","value_2":"def","value_3":"ghi","value_4":"jkl"}]},{"header":"OTHER HEADER","data":[{"value_0":"hello","value_1":"abc","value_2":"def","value_3":"ghi","value_4":"jkl"},{"value_0":"yello","value_1":"abc","value_2":"def","value_3":"ghi","value_4":"jkl"}]},{"header":"YET ANOTHER HEADER","data":[{"value_0":"hello","value_1":"abc","value_2":"def","value_3":"ghi","value_4":"jkl"},{"value_0":"hello","value_1":"abc","value_2":"def","value_3":"ghi","value_4":"jkl"}]}];


var key = 'value_0';
var val = 'hello';
var search = '';

for(var i in list)
{
 for(var j in list[i]['data'])
  {
   if(typeof(list[i]['data'][j][key]) != 'undefined' && list[i]['data'][j][key] == val)
    {
     search = list[i]['data'][j];
     break; 
    }
  }
}
console.log(search)
```